Why does a class definition in one cell not recognize another class's fields made in another cell?
I used a Visual Studio Code's Polyglot notebook and wrote the following in 3 separate cells, in the order indicated below.
Cell 1:
class Z;

Cell 2:
class A
{
    public static void f()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Z.x);
    }
}

Cell 3:
class Z: A
{
    public static int x = 42;
}

I then executed the cells in order, and got the following error message.
'Z' does not contain a definition for 'x'


My original question was:

Is it possible, in C#, to write a (possibly abstract) class A that has a (possibly static) function with signature void f(B b), whose parameter's type B is a (possibly abstract) class that derives from A (class B: A {...})? If not, why not?

and it was titled Can a C# class use a derived class?
I accepted the answer below based on this formulation. This formulation was later deleted by another user who edited my question, and changed its title.

why not just try it out yourself?

@MakePeaceGreatAgain The fact that I can't do something doesn't imply that it can't be done, and it doesn't explain why.

So you have tried it? What's the code you tried and what was the error message?

https://dotnetfiddle.net/rQrRqA

true, but if you'd tried it out, chances are you're answering the question already. Which is definitly the case here.

Please elaborate on "I can't do something". This sounds like you tried something and got an error.

I tried it in a Visual Studio Code Polyglot notebook, writing the classes in two separate cells, and it didn't work. But I guess if I write both of them in the same cell, then it works.

and what error specifically did you get? "Didn't work" isn't a proper problem-description, it can mean anything.

why did you even use cell 1, when you define the class in cell 3 anyway? I think when you delete cell1 it should work as intended.

If you place all 3 parts in to a single cell then the code is invalid as there are multiple declarations of class Z. If you then remove the initial class Z; the code would then be valid and should work as expected.

@MakePeaceGreatAgain Because I thought the error was due to the fact that class A wasn't aware of the existence of class Z.

@phuzi Yes, this is what I did. I merged cells 2 and 3, and executed this merged cell.

@EvanAad thanks for accepting my answer based on the original question context. However next time I think that instead of changing the context you'd better simply post a new question.

@MakePeaceGreatAgain I thought I understood the original question which seems quite striaghtforward, and answered accordingly. I don't see why you think I was not fair in doing so. As I mentioned above I think the question's context should not be changed to invalidate existing answer(s). Please explain where did I behave in an unfair way (I agree keeping a fair behavior is important here) ?

@wohlstad I just ment: personally I missed the bigger picture, that's why I voted to close. If you think, the question was clear enough, feel free to answer - and potentially miss the point. I didn't want to offend you.

@MakePeaceGreatAgain no harm done. In retrospect I agree the bigger picture was indeed relevant for the actual issue the OP had. But it seemed quite straightforward to me when I read it initialy.

Yes, it is possible.
Here's an example that follows exactly what you requested:
using System;

class A
{
    public void f(B b)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("in A.f.  b.Prop=" + b.Prop.ToString());
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public int Prop { get; set; } = 0;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        B b1 = new B();
        b1.Prop = 1;
        B b2 = new B();
        b2.Prop = 2;
        b1.f(b2);
        A a = new A();
        a.f(b1);
    }
}

Output:
in A.f.  b.Prop=2
in A.f.  b.Prop=1

Live demo
Note:
Since you asked, A and/or B can also be abstract.

Update:
The questiom was editted after this answer was given, with additional details about the usage of Polyglot notebook.
Regarding this additional information: the problem is related to the way the notebook executes the cells one by one. It is not an issue related to C# in general or the usage of inheritance in particular.

The notebook executes the cells one by one. So when you execute cell 2, Z is nothing but a class, without any notion of x. That's why you get the error.
It's not clear what behaviour you actually want. Of course you can just write the entire code into a single cell:
class A
{
    public static void f()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Z.x);
    }
}    
class Z: A
{
    public static int x = 42;
}

So your problem is not related to inheritance, but to how Polyglot executes the cells. Be aware, though, that your approach is pretty strange. A base-class should never make any assumptions about derived classes, this it it shouldn't even know that there exist any derived classes in the first place. However that's more of a conceptual problem, which is way too broad for this questions scope.

As an aside (to the OP), typically it's considered strange to access a child's members from a parent's (calling Z.<anything> from within A). You may want to really interrogate why you're doing that and refactor if possible.

Yes, sure. This is fully valid:
class A
{
   public B GetDerived() => new B();
}

class B : A
{
   // ...
}


Of course, the two classes need to be in the same assembly, because they need to know each other. The other question is for a relevant use case, which I find hard to imagine. Normally, if A is abstract, you would return A's (which then need to be derived types of A), and not B's, since that prevents you from later creating a class C that derives from A and which would replace B.
